# No surjective bounded linear map from $\ell^2(\mathbf{N})$ to $\ell^1(\mathbf{N})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The second part of an exercise asks that I show:

> There does not exist a surjective bounded linear map from $\ell^2(\mathbf{N})$ to $\ell^1(\mathbf{N})$.

The first part was to show that these two spaces are separable in their respective $L^p$ norms.

I've really hit a wall on this one.  I know, in fact, that there *does* exist a surjective bounded linear map from $\ell^1(\mathbf{N})$ to $\ell^2(\mathbf{N})$.  So my intuition says that if there were also one going the other way, then the two spaces would have to be isomorphic, which is false .  But I don't know of any such theorem that I could apply to "the category of Banach spaces".

My only other idea is to argue by contradiction using the open mapping theorem, but nothing is coming to me...  My guess is that separability is also going to be important, given the first part of the exercise.

-Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to use the answer suggested by Jochen above, given the unresolved issue of whether the map suggested by Omnomnomnom is open (see the comments).  If this becomes resolved, then I will accept Omnomnomnom's answer over this one.  If you wish to resolve this issue, please do so here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317152/is-this-map-of-banach-spaces-open

**Answer:**  Suppose $\phi \colon \ell^2 \twoheadrightarrow \ell^1$ is a surjective bounded linear map.  Then $\ell^2 / M \cong \ell^1$ as Banach spaces, where $M = \ker \phi$.  But the quotient of a reflexive normed linear space by a closed subspace is reflexive; e.g. see:

https://books.google.com/books?id=AwHrBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=quotient+space+is+reflexive&source=bl&ots=0e8I-fhnTm&sig=KAKQpcT3T4ib00XB5SNDkSt0Yog&hl=en&sa=X&ei=iaZ1VeD0HJWvyASe6YGYAg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=quotient%20space%20is%20reflexive&f=false

Since $\ell^2$ is reflexive and $\ell^1$ is not, we have a contradiction.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Both of these spaces are separable. Note that $\ell^2$ is isomorphic to its dual space, but the dual space of $\ell^1$ fails to be separable.

Note then that a surjection from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^1$ would induce an injection from $(\ell^1)'$ to $(\ell^2)'$.

Comment: A similar argument. $\ell^2$ is reflexive, quotients of reflexive spaces are reflexive and $\ell^1$ is not reflexive.

Comment: Regarding the answer, the only problem I'm having at the moment is showing the injection $(\ell^1)^\prime \hookrightarrow (\ell^2)^\prime$ is in fact an imbedding, i.e., its inverse is also bounded (equivalently, its image is closed in $(\ell^2)^\prime$).  We need this because we want to realize $(\ell^1)^\prime$ as an imbedded Banach space in $(\ell^2)^\prime$, from which we get the contradiction that $(\ell^1)^\prime$ becomes separable.

Comment: And just so we're clear, if $\phi \colon \ell^2 \to \ell^1$ is our assumed surjection, I'm defining $\phi^\prime \colon (\ell^1)^\prime \to (\ell^2)^\prime$ by $\phi^\prime(\varphi) = \varphi \circ \phi$.

Comment: @Jochen: I'm sure your answer is fine, but I am not so comfortable working with quotients in this setting, so I would like to at least make sure I understand the more concrete answer before thinking about the one you suggest. (Although I admit "concrete" is often synonymous with "preferred" in a situation such as this.)

Comment: @Doug we don't need the image of the surjection to be a Banach space; we just need it to be separable.

Comment: I am confused. Am I correct that the contradiction we are creating is that $(\ell^1)^\prime$ is both separable and not separable?

Comment: And that the way we are doing this is by imbedding it into the separable space $(\ell^2)^\prime$?

Comment: If this is so, then we at least need the injection to be a topological imbedding, and we are back to the problem of showing the inverse mapping is continuous (i.e. bounded).

Comment: Is it true that $D = \left\{ f \in \ell^\infty(\mathbf{N}) \colon ||f|| \leq 1 \right\}$ is compact?  If so, I think I can leverage (1) $(\ell^1)^\prime \cong \ell^\infty$, (2) $(\ell^1)^\prime$ is separable if and only if $B$ is separable, and (3) a continuous bijection whose domain is compact is a homeomorphism; to conclude that the injection is indeed a topological imbedding.

Comment: The unit ball is never compact in an infinite dimensional space

Comment: And we do have bounded injections from $\ell^\infty$ to $\ell^2$, in particular, we can take
$$
\xi_j \mapsto \frac{\xi_j}{j}
$$
so I guess you're right: we would need to show that $\phi'$ is an open mapping for this to give us a contradiction.

Comment: I didn't really think the argument through when I posted... not sure what the missing step would be.  This feels like the right kind of answer, though